# Ruby on Rails using Sidekiq to populate MongoDB database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, sidekiq

I'm trying to performe some async tasks using Sidekiq. More precisely, I want to insert in MongoDB collection some values.

For any reason it is not working.

hard_worker.rb

```
class HardWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(name)
      Blog.create(:name => name)
  end
end
```

controller.rb

```
def search  
  if(params[:name].empty?)
    @blogs = Blog.all
  else
    @blogs = Blog.where(name: params[:name])
    if(@blogs.empty?)
      HardWorker.perform_async(params[:name])
    end
   end
end
```

If I insert Blog.create(params[:name]) in controller.rb it works fine. But when I try to insert a document in async task it does not insert nothing.

Any idea?

Kind Regards,
Hugo

Comment: You probably need to add Kiqstand (https://github.com/mongoid/kiqstand) if you haven't already.

Comment: Is redis setup to run the `default` queue? Is the job being registered?

Comment: Are you actually running Sidekiq in a terminal?

Comment: Also, sidekiq eager loads the environment by default, so if you've made changes, you'll need to restart it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have a bad environment configured. As stated on some comments, you could be having one of the following problems:

1. Not having sidekiq running
2. Didnt fully restarted sidekiq after code change
3. The sidekiq client and server are running under different redis.

Try to debug one by one of the cases above and lemme know if the problem still persists.

Comment: I changed from Sidekiq to Resque and it is already working. Thank you anyway!